# Попытка чтения или записи

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Вот такая проблема. При компиляции программы выводит сообщение:

> `An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in ttt.exe
> Additional information: Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена.`

Как это исправить? Всё пишется в Visual Studio 2010. С++. Транслятор с языка Паскаль на язык Си.

Как я понял, проблема в открытии файла

> `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xce320dfa`

Нет доступа к памяти. Ошибку в коде показывает на это

```
c = instr[inpos+slen];
```

Как исправить или разрешить этот доступ к памяти?

Comment: Почему "при компиляции программы"? Это ошибка времени выполнения. "Как исправить" - хех, ну и вопрос. Это же ваша ошибка, кому как не вам знать как ее исправить. UPD Упс, не заметил что вопрос древний.

Answer (score 1):

С высокой степенью вероятности, ошибка связана с неверной индексацией массива. Индекс выходит за границы и идет обращение к несуществующей памяти. Либо переменная вообще не инициализирована. Чтобы исправить:

1. убедиться, что индекс не выходит за границы массива во время выполнения,
2. убедиться, что переменная проинициализирована до начала использования.